# Assigned vs <> nil

Tags: delphi, pointers, null

Is there any difference between `If Assigned(Foo)` and `If (Foo <> nil)`? If So, when should they each be used?

Comment: Assigned() reads better

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But `if not Assigned(foo)` get's kind of bloated compared to `if foo<>nil`. Having said that, i prefer `Assigned`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**TL;DR**

[The official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Assigned) states

> `Assigned(P)` corresponds to the test `P <> nil` for a pointer variable, and `@P <> nil` for a procedural variable.

Hence, for a non-procedural pointer variable (such as a variable of type `PInteger`, `PMyRec`, `TBitmap`, `TList<integer>`, or `TFormClass`), `Assigned(P)` is the same thing as `P <> nil`.

However, for a procedural variable, `Assigned(P)` is the same thing as `@P <> nil`, while `P <> nil` would try to *execute* the procedure or function that `P` points to (with an empty list of parameters).

**Explanation**

The documentation excerpt above summarizes it pretty well. `Assigned(X)` returns `True` if and only if the `X` variable, which has to be a pointer under the hood (with some exception), has a non-`nil` value.

`Assigned` can be used for "old-school" pointer variables:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  p: PInteger;
begin
  i := 5;

  p := @i;
  { Assigned(p)        True }
  { p <> nil           True }

  p := nil;
  { Assigned(p)        False }
  { p <> nil           False }
```

`Assigned` can also be used for object (and metaclass) variables. Indeed, in Delphi, an object (or metaclass) variable is simply a pointer under the hood:

```
L := TList<integer>.Create;
try
  { Assigned(L)        True }
  { L <> nil           True }
finally
  FreeAndNil(L);
end;

{ Assigned(L)          False }
{ L <> nil             False }
```

(And, for completeness, an example with a metaclass variable:

```
var
  FC: TFormClass;
begin

  FC := TForm;
  { Assigned(FC)       True }
  { FC <> nil          True }

  FC := nil;
  { Assigned(FC)       False }
  { FC <> nil          False }
```

)

In all these examples, `Assigned(X)` is exactly the same thing as `X <> nil`.

However, for procedural types, things are slightly different.

First, let's warm up:

```
type
  TStringProc = procedure(const AText: string);

procedure MyStrProc(const AText: string);
begin
  ShowMessage(AText);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SP: TStringProc;
begin
  SP := MyStrProc;
  SP('test');
end;
```

Notice in particular that `SP` is used to actually invoke the procedure it currently points to.

Now, you might try

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SP: TStringProc;
begin
  SP := MyStrProc;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(SP), True)); { True }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(SP <> nil, True)); { will not compile }

  SP := nil;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(SP), True)); { False }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(SP <> nil, True)); { will not compile }
end;
```

but that will not even compile. The compiler says, "Not enough actual parameters". The reason is that the above code will try to *execute* the procedure that `SP` points to, and then indeed the required `AText` parameter is missing. (Of course, at compile time, the compiler doesn't know if `SP` will point to a compatible procedure or not, but it *does* know the signature of such a valid procedure.)

And even if the procedural type had an empty parameter list, it wouldn't compile, since a procedure doesn't return a value (much less a value that can be compared against `nil`).

But beware! The following code *will* compile:

```
type
  TGetPtrFunc = function: pointer;

function MyPtrFunc: pointer;
begin
  Result := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  PF: TGetPtrFunc;
begin
  PF := MyPtrFunc;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(PF), True)); { True }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(PF <> nil, True)); { False (!) }

  PF := nil;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(PF), True)); { False }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(PF <> nil, True)); { will cause access violation at runtime }
end;
```

The first `PF <> nil` will compare the `MyPtrFunc` function result value against `nil`; it will **not** tell you whether the `PF` function pointer is assigned or not (it is!).

The second `PF <> nil` will try to invoke a `nil` function pointer; that's a bug (access violation exception).

To test if a procedural variable is assigned, you have to test `@PF <> nil`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SP: TStringProc;
begin
  SP := MyStrProc;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(SP), True)); { True }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(@SP <> nil, True)); { True }

  SP := nil;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(SP), True)); { False }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(@SP <> nil, True)); { False }
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  PF: TGetPtrFunc;
begin
  PF := MyPtrFunc;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(PF), True)); { True }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(@PF <> nil, True)); { True }

  PF := nil;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(PF), True)); { False }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(@PF <> nil, True)); { False }
end;
```

For procedural variables, `Assigned(X)` is the same thing as `@X <> nil`, as stated by the documentation.

**Methods**

Methods work as regular procedures as far as this topic is concerned. For instance, for a method variable `M`, `Assigned(M)` is equivalent to `@M <> nil` and is `True` iff the method pointer is not `nil`. (Under the hood, I believe `@M` yields the `Code` member of `TMethod`.)

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  M: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  M := Self.FormClick;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(M), True)); { True }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(@M <> nil, True)); { True }

  M := nil;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(M), True)); { False }
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(@M <> nil, True)); { False }
end;
```

**What to use?**

So, should you use `Assigned(X)` or `X <> nil` for non-procedural pointers? And should you use `Assigned(X)` or `@X <> nil` for procedural pointers? It is entirely a matter of taste.

*Personally*, I tend to use `Assigned(X)` when I want to test if the variable is assigned, and `X = nil` (or `@X = nil`) when I want to test if the variable is *not* assigned, simply because `not Assigned(X)` is less compact.

**A related warning**

Of course, both `Assigned(X)` and `X <> nil` (or `@X <> nil`) only test if the pointer is `nil` or not; if non-`nil`, the pointer might still point to garbage. For instance, since local non-managed variables are not initialized in Delphi, they might well be non-`nil` before they are assigned a value, but in that case they point to garbage:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  L: TList<integer>; { local non-managed variable: not initialized }
begin
  Assigned(L) { True or False (chance). If True, it points to garbage data. }
              { Bad things will happen if you try to use L as a list here }
              { (especially if L is not nil). }
```

Another example:

```
  L := TList<integer>.Create;
  try
    { Do things with L }
  finally
    L.Free;
  end;

  Assigned(L); { True, but L points to garbage -- don't use it as a list! }
```

Comment: I think that the question is just about language. In the same fashion we have MyType(Myvar).Prop which is the same as (MyVar as MyType).Prop

Comment: @az01: if MyVar does not have an instance of MyType `as` fail with an exception. `MyType(MyVar).Prop` doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Assigned() can handle any object as arguments and is always what you want to call.
If you get a null value, you definitly want to test it as "not assigned" rather than have an exception because null <> nil.